# How do I switch the running codes using the IF?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, datetime, if-statement

Bear with me, I just started learning JS yesterday trying to make a HTML clock by putting multiple tutorials' results together.

I made two looping animations using 2 arrays, with the intent of switching between arrays depending on if it's earlier or later than 8pm. I would like for my code to constantly check if it's 8pm every X amount of seconds, and only re-run the script if the `IF` result or output is different than what it currently is.

```
const now = new Date();
if (now.getHours() > 20) { // Time checker!!!!!
    var hat = ['A','B','C','D'], 
        a = -1;
    (function f(){
        a = (a + 1) % hat.length;
        const hatformatted = `${(hat[ a ])}`;
        document.querySelector(".main").textContent = hatformatted;
        setTimeout(f, 1000);
    })();    
} else {
        var hat = ['1','2','3','4'], 
        a = -1;
    (function f(){
        a = (a + 1) % hat.length;
        const hatformatted = `${(hat[ a ])}`;
        document.querySelector(".main").textContent = hatformatted;
        setTimeout(f, 1000);
    })();
}
```

I have tried `setInterval` however it re-runs the script even if the `IF` result has not changed, and messes up the animation.

I.E - if it's 6pm, it tries to play the animation from the start every 1 second and the frames get messed up.

Any advice or help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to save your code.

```
const checkTimeDelay = 1000;
let isAbove8PM = null;
let curTimeHandler = null;
let intervalId = null;

// checking if is above 8 pm
const checkTime = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    if (now.getHours() > 20) { 
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
};


const above8PMHandler = () => {
    var hat = ['A','B','C','D'], 
        a = -1;
    return () => {
        a = (a + 1) % hat.length;
        const hatformatted = `${(hat[ a ])}`;
        document.querySelector(".main").textContent = hatformatted;
        // setTimeout(f, 1000);
    };    
};

const before8PMHandler = () => {
    var hat = ['1','2','3','4'], 
    a = -1;
    return () => {
        a = (a + 1) % hat.length;
        const hatformatted = `${(hat[ a ])}`;
        document.querySelector(".main").textContent = hatformatted;
        // setTimeout(f, 1000);
    };
};

// restart clock interval on based on new handler (above8PMHandler|before8PMHandler)
const rebaseClockInterval = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = setInterval(curTimeHandler, 1000);
};

// main func, checks if we should change clocks handler (above8PMHandler|before8PMHandler)
const clockTick = () => {
    const curTimeChecked = checkTime();
    if (curTimeChecked === isAbove8PM) { return; }
    
    isAbove8PM = curTimeChecked;
    if (isAbove8PM) {
        curTimeHandler = above8PMHandler();
    } else {
        curTimeHandler = before8PMHandler();
    }
    curTimeHandler(); 
    rebaseClockInterval();
};

// start main func
setInterval(clockTick, checkTimeDelay);
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your answer fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I also provide some ideas here.

```
function setClockInterval() {
  const hat1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
  const hat2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

  let prevCheck = null;
  let count = 0;

  const checker = () => {
    return new Date().getSeconds() > 20;
  };

  const next = () => {
    count++;
  };

  const reset = () => {
    count = 0;
  };

  const render = (content) => {
    // console.log(`clockInterval ${content}`); // debug output
    document.querySelector(".main").textContent = content;
  };

  const fn = () => {
    const check = checker();
    const arr = check ? hat1 : hat2;

    // empty arr skip
    if (arr.length <= 0)
      return;

    // restart count to 0
    if (prevCheck !== null && prevCheck !== check)
      reset();

    render(arr[count % arr.length]);

    prevCheck = check;
    next();
  };

  return setInterval(fn, 1000);
}

// start interval
const clock = setClockInterval();

// stop
clearInterval(clock);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your code by removing everything from inside the *if* block that is repeated and running it afterward. You also need to get a new Date on each iteration, otherwise the array won't change when it gets to the designated time.

I have changed the condition check to be odd/even seconds to show how it swaps between arrays without losing the index.

```js
// Global, could be kept inside closure
let a = -1;

// Function to run each iteration
(function f() {
  // OP code
  // let hat = new Date().getHours() > 18? ['A','B','C','D'] : ['1','2','3','4'];
  // faster iteration as example
  let hat = new Date().getSeconds() % 2? ['A','B','C','D'] :['1','2','3','4'];
  a = (a + 1) % hat.length;
  document.querySelector(".main").textContent = hat[a];
  setTimeout(f, 1000);
})();
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```